# CoreData not removing relationship between items

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
      RPCoreData *manager = [RPCoreData sharedManager];
      if (manager.IdsArray) {
          NSPredicate *itemFilter = [NSPredicate
              predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (id IN %@)", manager.IdsArray];
          NSArray *itemArray = [ItemData MR_findAllWithPredicate:itemFilter];
          for (ItemData *itemData in itemArray) {
              NSPredicate *categoryFilter =
                  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", itemData.category.id];
              CategoryData *categoryDataInLocalContext =
                  [CategoryData MR_findFirstWithPredicate:categoryFilter inContext:localContext];
              if (![categoryDataInLocalContext isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                  [categoryDataInLocalContext removeRelationshipObject:itemData];
              }
          }
      }

    }
        completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"%i %@", success, error);
        }];
```

NSlog prints out No, nil.

The relationship between CategoryData and ItemData is not being removed.
Category has a one to many relationship with ItemData

Comment: have you checked `manager.IdsArray` actually contains something? debug and look at all the variables, what isn't found that you expect to be. you don't actually need to fetch the category as you already have it in the relationship...

Comment: you shouldn't do `[ItemData MR_findAllWithPredicate:itemFilter]` in this code as you're accessing the wrong context... (IIRC this uses the main context)

Comment: @Wain thanks that works. I'm always forgetting a local context somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the relationship by simply setting

```
for (ItemData *itemData in itemArray) {
  itemData.categoryData = nil
}
```

No need to fetch the CategoryData. If you delete the relationship from the itemData side it is also removed from the CategoryData side.

Just make sure that the `Delete rule` is set to `Nullify` in your datamodel. Also check that you are in the correct context.